# How do I enable openssl for PHP on AWS EC2 (to use for backend calls only - not incoming traffic)?

Tags: php, ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-ec2

Here was the error received when trying to use file_get_contents() to pull a file from a remote secure server using the standard AWS EC2 setup:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message
>   'file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you
>   forget to enable it when you configured PHP?'

How do I fix this on AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run var_dump(stream_get_wrappers()) by placing it into its own PHP file. The result will look something like: (In this case it should show https, but it doesn't.)

   > ```
   > array(7) {
   >   [0]=>
   >   string(3) "php"
   >   [1]=>
   >   string(4) "file"
   >   [2]=>
   >   string(4) "glob"
   >   [3]=>
   >   string(4) "data"
   >   [4]=>
   >   string(4) "http"
   >   [5]=>
   >   string(3) "ftp"
   >   [6]=>
   >   string(13) "compress.zlib"
   > }
   > ```
2. Install the php_openssl package by running:

   > zypper install php-openssl

   (since you are most likely on Suse Linux. Otherwise, use yum instead of zypper.)
3. Restart apache using:

   > rcapache2 restart
4. Run your var_dump(stream_get_wrappers()) file again:

   > ```
   > array(9) {
   >   [0]=>
   >   string(3) "php"
   >   [1]=>
   >   string(4) "file"
   >   [2]=>
   >   string(4) "glob"
   >   [3]=>
   >   string(4) "data"
   >   [4]=>
   >   string(4) "http"
   >   [5]=>
   >   string(3) "ftp"
   >   [6]=>
   >   string(5) "https"
   >   [7]=>
   >   string(4) "ftps"
   >   [8]=>
   >   string(13) "compress.zlib"
   > }
   > ```

   As you can see, we now have the https wrapper.

I had originally thought that we would need to adjust /etc/php5/cli/php.ini. But at the end of the process you can see my php.ini still has the php_openssl commented out.

> ```
> cat /etc/php5/cli/php.ini | grep openssl
> ;extension=php_openssl.dll
> ```

Also, I was running as the root user through this whole process, so you probably need to run as root or add sudo before each command.

Answer (score 0):

1: Check which wrappers are installed.

2: If you dont see "https" on the list, add to/uncomment from `php.ini`

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```